# Spring WebClient and Eureka Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, netflix-eureka, spring-webclient

spring webclient unable to retrieve the actual host from service instance name  from eureka server and getting below exception :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: USER-DATA-SERVICE
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://USER-DATA-SERVICE/users/01 [DefaultWebClient]
```

Spring boot version : 2.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT &
Spring cloud version : Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Please provide more information such as your dependencies and configuration and the output of `http://<eurekaserver>/eureka/apps`

Comment: Consumer Client application.yml
--------------------------------

spring :
  application :
    name : user-info-service
        
server :
  port : 8801
  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8700/eureka/

Comment: Discovery Client application.yml
------------------------------------

spring:
   application:
      name: user-eureka-discovery-service

server:
   port: 8700
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${spring.application.name}:${server.port}/eureka/

Comment: same coding working fine RestTemplate but if we change webClient then getting unkownhost exception

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, but I found that @Bean tag was missing on the web client instance creation method. You can also use @LoadBalanced annotation if you are spinning more than one instance

Add below code in your application class.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder getWebClient(){
    return WebClient.builder();
}
```

this should resolve error, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

if the answer from @Bhavesh does still not working then make sure to add AddressResolver to your httpClient. Lets see how:

First of all, don't forget to add the preferring of IP-address in properties:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

**USEING Reactor HttpClient**

```
import io.netty.resolver.DefaultAddressResolverGroup;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;


@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClientReactor() {
        return HttpClient.create()
                .resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
    }


    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder(HttpClient httpClient) {

        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));
    }

}
```